# Access urls on the local network in windows metro

Tags: http, networking, microsoft-metro

I have two computers behind a router on the same network.  On computer A, I'm serving a web page via HTTP.  On computer B, I'm running windows 8.

In Internet Explorer 8 Desktop Mode, I can type in the IP address of computer A and view a page.  However, in metro mode, it says "This page can't be displayed".

I am trying to test out a metro app using a local server.  However, any attempt to communicate with computer A from computer B in a metro app fails.  All of my co-workers are experiencing the same problem.  It's not just IP addresses -- even domain names on our VPN don't work.

Comment: @dhopton no.  It's an ip address.  I've tried domains too.  It works in the desktop browsers but not in metro.

Comment: the iframe is likely because the policy isn't configured for that app. However that shouldn't effect Metro IE. However, i can access .'d IPs right now in Metro IE on RP no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well; turns out it was blocked by the capabilities restrictions.

In your app manifest, check the "Private Networks (Client & Server)" box (or add the "privateNetworkClientServer" capability in the XML.